# The set of all polynoms are closed at $d(x,y)=\max\limits_{[a,b]} \mid x(t)-y(t)\mid$?

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces

> Prove or disprove with counter-example: the set of all polynoms are closed at $d(x,y)=\max\limits_{[a,b]} \mid x(t)-y(t)\mid$
>
> The polynoms in the interval $[a,b]$

*Attempt:*

counter-example: $y(t):=0,\quad x(t)=\sin t\quad;\quad 0\leqslant t\leqslant \pi$

$$\max\mid \sin t-0\mid=1$$

then $d(x,y)$ contain only the max value and not the edge therefore the set is not closed.

Comment: First of all, $\sin(t)$ is not a polynomial, right?

Comment: Stupid mistake, of course not

Comment: I can take $-t^2+1$ instead of $\sin t\quad $ $\max|-t^2+1-0|=1$

Comment: I have a question, is your metric space the space of all continuous functions $f[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ with the aforementioned metric ?

Comment: Yes @CarryonSmiling $~~~~~$

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassApproximationTheorem.html)?

Comment: Good point, by Weirstras's approximation theorem the closure of the set of polynomials is in fact the whole space of continuous functions !! So it is far from a closed set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We pick the interval $[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}]$

Consider the polynomial $P_k(x)=1+x+x^2+\dots x^k$

it is not hard to show $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}P_k=f$ where $f$ is defined by $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$. (not a polynomial).

To show that it holds for the interval $[a,b]$ just consider $Q_k=P_k\circ h$ with $h$ any polynomial that maps $[a,b]$ to $[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}]$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no: it is not closed.

Take for example the exponential map $\exp(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$. Each partial sum $\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ is a polynomial, and they converge in the sup norm - which is the norm you specified - to the exponential map, which is not a polynomial.